# Android asynctask warring like arargs methods should only override or be overridden by other varargs methods

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have implemented Android async task class, here am overridden `doInBackground(String[])` method but code is working am getting warning like

```
Varargs methods should only `override` or be overridden by other `varargs` methods unlike new `JSONTask(){}.doInBackground(String[])` and `JSONTask.doInBackground(String...)`
```

JSONTask class

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ///String mJsonString =  doing my stuff..................

        return mJsonString;
    }

    }
```

i have two class ClassA and ClassB, i have used JSONTask in both class i have override doInBackground() method , but the code is working perfect but is showing warring like 
    Varargs methods should only override or be overridden by other varargs methods unlike new JSONTask(){}.doInBackground(String[]) and JSONTask.doInBackground(String...).

ClassA code

```
class ClassA
    {

    new JSOnTask()
    {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ///String mJsonString =  doing my stuff..................

        return mJsonString;
    }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }


    }.execute(params);
    }
```

ClassB code

```
class ClassB
    {

    new JSOnTask()
    {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ///String mJsonString =  doing my stuff..................

        return mJsonString;
    }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }


    }.execute(params);
    }
```

how to avoid this warring...
Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher can u check now, i have update code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doInBackground()` method signature is

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

which expects variable arguments as parameter, but when you override this method like

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] strings)
```

by passing `String` array instead of `String` var args

here compiler will not show any error but warns you(the warning as you said)