# protected void onPostExecute error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

When I try to implement the onPostExecute method it gives me an error to remove @Override and that a super class or method needs to be called. However, I did call the superclass and such. Here is my code of my Asynctask.

```
    public class parsenfill extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
        JsonParsing parse = new JsonParsing(url);
        parse.parseFile(3, urls);
        return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void...voids ) {
        super.onPostExecute(voids);
                    //Body of method

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275824/android-asynctask-warring-like-arargs-methods-should-only-override-or-be-overrid

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `...` from the method signature. The parameter type of `onPostExecute` is the return type of `doInBackground()` i.e. just plain `Void` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        /**
         * invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step
         * is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a
         * progress bar in the user interface.
         */

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /**
         * Invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute()
         * finishes executing. This step is used to perform background
         * computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the
         * asynchronous task are passed to this step.
         */
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        /**
         * Invoked on the UI thread after the background computation
         * finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to
         * this step as a parameter.
         */
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Then you have to call this **async class** on UI thread like this.

```
new MyAsyncClass().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Wrong:

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void...voids ) {
    super.onPostExecute(voids);
                //Body of method

}
```

because ... stands for string array and your background returns void.

## Correct:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void voids ) {
    super.onPostExecute(voids);
                //Body of method

}
```